# CasperJS: Proper way to close page instances while looping

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have a long-running script that loops across several different links to perform its work. I encountered a scenario where PhantomJS ran out of resources due to the page objects not being garbage collected since I'm reusing it. I have a simple example below. I close() the page object and create a new one at the end of each loop cycle, but after I do that Casper just hangs. What is the proper way to do this?

```
var links = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];

var casper = require('casper').create({
    logging: 'error',
    pageSettings: {
        webSecurityEnabled: false
    }
});

casper.start('http://www.amazon.com', function () {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.eachThen(links, function(item) {
    var url = item.data;
    this.open(url).then(function (){
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    }).then(function (){
        casper.page.close();
        casper.page = require('webpage').create();
    });
});

casper.run(function (){
    this.echo('Done');
});
```

This will output

```
Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more
Google
```

and then just hang.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var urls = ['http://google.com/', 'http://yahoo.com/'];

casper.start().eachThen(urls, function(response) {
  this.thenOpen(response.data, function(response) {
      this.echo('\n'+this.getTitle());
  });
});

casper.run(function(){
    this.die('\n'+'Done');
});
```

this worked for me. its from the documentation... I'm not sure casperjs requires you to close the page.

Comment: [`casper.exit()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html?highlight=gettitle#exit) also works